# Autovacuum does not start. How to understand the reason? Cost-based auto vacuum is already disabled

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, autovacuum

PostgreSQL v12. Database cluster size: 12+ Tb (30+ databases 100-600Gb each). Server: 40 cores, 128Gb ram.

For some reason, autovacuum stopped running. How to understand the reason?
Yesterday, the workers were running every minute for each base (according to the settings), but then they stopped and are no longer running.

Settings:

```
autovacuum = on

autovacuum_max_workers = 4
autovacuum_naptime = 1min

autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.10
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 1000
```

For example, here is a table in one of the databases:

```
relname: ods_storage_sync_queue
n_live_tup: 8
n_dead_tup: 180542
autovacuum_count: 74167
last_autovacuum: 2023-09-26 18:48:11.868
last_autoanalyze: 2023-09-26 18:48:11.869
```

The table contains an infinite number of dead tuples, but autovacuum does not clean it.

Another example:

```
relname: ods_storage_sync_queue
n_live_tup: 11434
n_dead_tup: 2064
autovacuum_count: 16727
last_autovacuum: 2023-09-26 18:13:21.612
last_autoanalyze: 2023-09-26 18:47:11.530
```

There are 18% dead tupples. According to autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 10%, autovacuum should have started a long time ago, but a day has passed... nothing happens, although yesterday everything started once a minute, as set in autovacuum_naptime.

What else can I check? How to understand the reason?

Comment: "Cost-based auto vacuum is already disabled"  What does that mean?  Are you describing that `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0`, or are you trying to say something else?

Comment: Is the background proces still running or not? And could you find anything about autovacuum in your logfiles?

Comment: The only evidence you showed us that two small tables have not been vacuumed in a while.  A plausible explanation for this is that all 4 of your allowed autovac workers got "pinned down" working on 4 large tables that all came due at the same time, so there are no more available workers to work on other things.  You can look at the pg_stat_progress_vacuum view to see if that might be the case.

Comment: Cost-based autovacuum - yes, I've set autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0 and for one day the autovacuum worked clearly, starting once a minute for each database

Comment: In processes running only autovacuum launcher, no worker. Sometimes I've saw one worker for one database in the cluster.

Comment: Only launcher in processes:

 5066 ?        Ss     0:58 postgres: 12/ssng_pds: autovacuum launcher

Comment: pg_stat_progress_vacuum is empty on any database in cluster.

Some comment: we have standby replica, but it works fine.

Comment: If I restart postgresql, 3 workers are immediately started (why not 4?), which disappear from the processes after working. Logs contains only information about their work, no errors and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described problem was solved by updating PostgreSQL from 12.1 to 12.16. We found in Release Notes that somewhere along the way from 12.1 to 12.16 an error was fixed that caused autovacuum to be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The one possibility is that autovacuum really does not run. You should set `log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0` and examine your log file to see if that is the case. Reasons for autovacuum not starting are

- The statistics collector process has a problem. That is not the case here, since you see the number of dead tuples increasing.
- All 4 slots of `autovacuum_max_workers` are already taken by long-running autovacuum workers, and other tables that need `VACUUM` have to wait until one of them finishes. You can diagnose that with `pg_stat_activity`, and the solution would be to increase `autovacuum_max_workers`.

However, it is likely that autovacuum does run, but is prevented from cleaning up dead tuples. As detailed in [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/), there are four possible reasons:

- a concurrent long running transaction
- a stale replication slot
- an orphaned prepared transaction
- a lagging standby with `hot_standby_feedback = on`

Comment: log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0 is already set and today autovacuum started working again and is now running once a minute in each database.

At night, we manually (cron) run "vacuum (analyze, skip_locked)" for all tables with dead_tup > 5%. There is a feeling that after that autovacuum started working, at least according to the logs it turns out that way. But why? And when it stops working again - how to understand what is stopping him?

Comment: We use replication slot, but it used and active.
Also we have hot_standby_feedback = on, but standby replica works fine...

Long running transactions... yes, sometimes. But not for 24 hours :) And not in all databases in cluster.

Comment: If `log_autovacuum_min_duration` logs nothing, then autovacuum indeed did not run. Or it did run, but the four workers took forever, so that no new ones could be started. Look at the duration in the autovacuum log entries right after the long intermission.

Comment: There is grep of log file: https://gist.github.com/xpg934/e5e8c84d71b6e26dbda32846ccb072e9
There are no long autovacuum launches.

However, there are oddities. For example, in 2023-09-25 22:49:17.419 there is an entry, and the next one is in 2023-09-26 02:42:02.150 (at 02:00 we start a manual vacuum and somewhere at 02:42 it finished working on all databases).

And today was the same.

Comment: I see nothing to worry about. There can only be one `VACUUM` running on a table at a given time, so if you start a manual `VACUUM` on the table, no autovacuum will run on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to worry :( because if autovacuum does not work, then after a few hours serious slowdowns in query execution begin, up to a complete stop of our services. We have to run vacuum manually at these moments, which allows us to restore work.

Comment: What makes you think that autovacuum doesn't work? If you run a manual `VACUUM` it cannot run on the same table at the same time.

Comment: I'm looking at n_dead_tup and last_autovacuum. Yesterday, while there were massive updates in the tables, the autovacuum was working and cleaning the accumulated once a minute. Next it stopped at 22:15, because the clients have completed their work. Today the work has started, but there is no autovacuum - again, n_dead_up is accumulating heavily and the value in last_autovacuum has remained unchanged since yesterday. For example:

relname: contact_pools 
n_live_tup: 153
n_dead_tup: 3312 (2164%)
last_autovacuum: 2023-09-28 21:58:00.031 

Autovacuum doesn't start for 12h...

Comment: Are there any autovacuum processes running at all? See `pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: No, "select * from pg_stat_activity where query like 'autovacuum:%';" - empty result.

Comment: Well, if dead tuple statistics keep growing in `pg_stat_user_tables`, no autovacuum process is running, autovacuum is not disabled and you have no high locks on the tables, then it can only be an act of god.

Comment: No, it's not God, it's programmers :) An error in PostgreSQL 12.1 that causes autovacuum to freeze. Updating to 12.16 solved the problem.

Comment: 12.1?! Well, you didn't mention that. Then you have yourself to blame for not updating regularly. Thanks for the feedback!